# How to create react UI library having mix of client and server components?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to create a simple library that exports some server components and some client components. It should be compatible with Nextjs app router. But when I build, the client components don't work.

I tried building the library with `tsup`. I can fix the client components issue by adding

```
 banner: {
     js: `"use client";`,
 },
```

to the `tsup.config.ts`. However, once I do that, server components break.

Answer (score -1):

Check out - https://github.com/mayank1513/esbuild-react18-useclient/. This is the library I created to solve this issue.

To use this library

```
pnpm add -D esbuild-react18-useclient
// or
npm install -D esbuild-react18-useclient
// or 
yarn add --dev esbuild-react18-useclient
```

And in tsup config

```
// tsup.config.ts or tsup.config.js
import { defineConfig } from "tsup";
import reactUseClient from "esbuild-react18-useclient";

export default defineConfig(options => ({
    ...
    esbuildPlugins:[reactUseClient]
}));
```

You can also check out the library that uses this library -> https://github.com/mayank1513/nextjs-themes

Feel free to start and / or fork and / or report issues for any or both of the libraries.

Happy to help!